# UITableView and NSFetchedResultsController row deletion error

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to delete a row from `UITableView` this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        let itemToDelete: Device = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Device
        (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(itemToDelete)
        self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

When I run I get this error:

```
Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (0) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).
```

Comment: Summary of the referenced thread: Just delete the managed object. Don't call `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths()`.

Comment: *Where* does the error occur now? Btw, there is no need to call performFetch() again.

Comment: I have rolled back the question to revision one because after your change the "duplicate" did not fit anymore, and also you did not provide any additional information. – Please ask a new question if necessary.